# Proof on set system

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

---

Let $\Omega$ be a uncountable set, and for the set systems we have
$$\mathcal{A}_1=\{A\subseteq \Omega\mid A\text{ is  finite}\}$$

Is $\mathcal{A}_1$ a Ring, $\sigma-$Ring or $\sigma-$Algebra?

---

According to the definition I know that $\mathcal{A}_1$ is a ring, because unions and differences of two arbitrary finite subsets are also finite, such that these two operations are closed in $\mathcal{A}_1$. But it's neither $\sigma-$Ring nor $\sigma-$Algebra, right? Because for the countble unions $\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=0} A_i$ with $A_{i}\in \mathcal{A}_1$, it may lead to a infinite set which will no longer be an elemente of $\mathcal{A}_1$, for example we can construct a series $A_i:=\{i\}$, then $ \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=0} A_i=\{\{0\}, \{1\},\ldots, {\infty}\}$. Is this proof correct?

Thanks a lot for your hints!

Comment: Main weapon to attack this problem is the result : Countable union of  finite set need not be finite (though countable) . For an example : $\Bbb{N}=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb {N}} \{n\}$

Comment: @SuccessfulFailure yes, it's exactly what I want to prove, thank you a lot! :)